# OSGi - Adding bundle's classes to specific classloader

Tags: java, groovy, osgi

I have bundle `A.jar` installed in OSGi and I can get this bundle using BundleContext

`Bundle bundleA = context.getBundle()`

And a specific classloader B

How can I adding all class from `bundleA` to my classloader B

Comment: You can't. Try to phrase your question in terms of the problem you're trying to solve, rather than the solution you already have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this at runtime. You can add a Require-Bundle  header to bundle B. Then the classloader of bundle B will know all classes of bundle A. This is not really recommended though.

So I would rather ask you what do you want to achieve with this? Perhaps there is another solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks , let me show you my system :

Assume that my system using OSGI ,in my OSGi environment installed `bundle A` and `bundle B`

- `Bundle A` provide service to execute some groovy script (called it `C.groovy`) and `C.groovy` using some class from bundle B

Problem is that the classloader is difference from OSGi and groovy script runtime

Please help me

Comment: In this case using the classloader like BJ described would help. Perhapss you can upgrade your OSGi framework?

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume you are writing your own class loader and want to use Bundle A's class loader as its parent. You can get the class loader for Bundle A as follows:

`ClassLoader clA = bundleA.adapt(BundleWiring.class).getClassLoader();`

You can then use `clA` as the parent of a new ClassLoader instance for loading your classes which depend upon classes from A.

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm using OSGi version 4.0.2 , I saw your solution somewhere but 4.0.2 have no apdapt() function for Bundle

Comment: Cool thing .. did not know it is possible to get the classloader. I also could have needed this some time ago.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by OSGi 4.0.2 since there is no such version of the OSGi specification. Perhaps you mean Apache Felix 4.0.2? I am unsure as it what version so the OSGi API the Felix 4.0.2 supports.